# Parameterizing with examples keyword in specflow issue

Tags: selenium, specflow

Working with parameterizing through examples keyword in specflow creating an issue.
Following is my scenario and code to insert password in the Field:

```html
Scenario Outline: Register Successfully
Given I am shown the Registration view
When I enter ComapnyName in the <CompanyName> field
And I enter UserName in the <UserName> field
And I enter Email in the <Email> field
And I enter Password in the  <Password> field
And I enter ConfirmPassword in the <ConfirmPassword> field
And I choose to register my account
Then my user account is created
And I am navigated to my company dashboard

Examples: 

| CompanyName | UserName      | Email                               | Password      | ConfirmPassword |
| XYZ         | Salman Haider | salman.haider@gmail.com             | FooBar@123    | FooBar@123      |
```

```
public void Password(string password, int n)
    {
        //Getting and Setting up the values in the Password Field
        var passwords = Helper.Driver.FindElements(By.XPath(".//*[@name='password']")).ToList();
        passwords[n].SendKeys(password);
        Thread.Sleep(2000);
    }
```

When it enters the password in the field and clicks on submit button shows a validation error that password should be 8 characters long,one capital and a special character required besides the password is all correct. However same code works working with parameterizing with table.

```html
Scenario: Register Successfully
Given I am shown the Registration view
When I enter credientials 
| CompanyName | UserName   | Email                              | Password      | ConfirmPassword |
| Seven       | Mobeen     | usama.rafiq@gmail.com              | FooBar@123    | FooBar@123      |

And I choose to register my account
Then my user account is created
And I am navigated to my company dashboard
```

. But I need former method to work as I have multiple test data to enter.

Comment: Could you post your scenarios also? I don't really understand what kind of bindings you want to write.

Comment: Hi @AndreasWillich is it right now?

Comment: Do I understand you right, that you want this scenario with different CompanyName/UserName combinations executed? Simple add a new line to the examples table.

Comment: That I can do for sure...But the problem is that when I enter record in fields it doesn't submit ,rather shows a validation error that password should be 8 characters long,one capital and a special character required. As you can see password is fulfilling the requirement but it shows an error. Same record can be enter via parameterizing through table method.